# ggplot2 add legend for each geom_point manually

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a plot using 2 separate data sets so that I could create different errorbars.  The first data set has error bars that go down only whereas the second data set has error bars that go up only.  This prevents unnecessary overlap in the plot. I also used a compound shape for one of the groups.

I want to create a legend based on these shapes (not a colour), but I can't seem to figure it out.  Here is the plot code.

```
p <-ggplot()
p + geom_point(data=df.figure.1a, aes(x=Hour, y=Mean), shape=5, size=4) +
    geom_point(data=df.figure.1a, aes(x=Hour, y=Mean), shape=18, size=3) +
    geom_errorbar(data=df.figure.1a, aes(x=Hour, y=Mean, ymin = Mean - SD, ymax = Mean), size=0.7, width = 0.4) +
    geom_point(data=df.figure.1b, aes(x=Hour, y=Mean), shape=17, size=4) +
    geom_errorbar(data=df.figure.1b, aes(x=Hour, y=Mean, ymin = Mean, ymax = Mean + SD), size=0.7, width = 0.4)
```

Comment: You are having a difficult time creating a legend because you decided to use two different data frames. Combine them into one, with an indicator variable to distinguish each group. Then map that variable to `shape` in `aes`.

Comment: That's fine, but then how do I create a different set of error bars for each line?

Comment: Same way, basically. But it's getting difficult to explain because you haven't provided a reproducible example.

Comment: This worked:`p<-ggplot()
p + geom_point(data=df.figure.1a, aes(x=Hour, y=Mean, shape=factor(HR_95)), size=4) +
  geom_errorbar(data=df.figure.1a, aes(x=Hour, y=Mean, ymin = Mean - SD, ymax = Mean), size=0.7, width = 0.4) +
  geom_point(data=df.figure.1b, aes(x=Hour, y=Mean, shape=factor(HR_95)), size=4) +
  geom_errorbar(data=df.figure.1b, aes(x=Hour, y=Mean, ymin = Mean, ymax = Mean + SD), size=0.7, width = 0.4) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "Groups", labels=c("A", "B"))`

Comment: I did have to give up creating my own shape out of two shapes though...

Comment: I'm glad that worked, but trust me, it would have been simpler (and much less typing) to combine the data frame.

Comment: I actually had to separate the data frame to create the two separate goem_points.  The key element that required this was my wanting to have different geom_errorbar elements for each group.  If there is a way to do that other than the way I did it, then that would be great.

Comment: I'm certain there is a way. But as I said, it's impossible for me to show you how without a reproducible example.